# VestaCP Error code 2

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, vesta

I tried to use `Lets Encrypt Support` under `SSL Support` section when I added a new domain name on web panel. I got this error message:

> Error code: 2

which means:

> E_INVALID   Object or argument is not valid

`Apache2` web server and `nginx` caching server are both active on server and running. Domains are pointed to server with `A` record, these are working through `HTTP`.

OS: `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab125.5 x86_64)`

VestaCP version: `0.9.8-18`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same for me.
I removed the FTP account, tried again, and then got the less cryptic error:

> Error: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for ...

So: Check your DNS records. Likely, a record is missing.

In my case though, one of the aliases specified in Vesta was no longer available as that domain had expired. I removed that alias and all was good again.